# How to simply CSS class with same properties except one property

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, less, bem

I am working on a react web app, which has 2 columns as leftCol and rightCol className. Both class have almost same property with z-index difference. following is the styling

```
&__rightCol {
​ position : relative;
 ​box-sizing: border-box;
 ​z-index: 0;

 ​&_box {
  ​display : none;
  ​}
}

&__leftCol {
  position : relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 1;

  &_box {
   display : none;
   }
}
```

how to simply these both classes, such that we use common class except z-index different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like you're using SASS/SCSS?

you can use `@mixin`

```
@mixin col {
  position : relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  &_box {
    display : none;
  }
}

.rightCol {
  @include col;

  z-index: 0;
}

.leftCol {
  @include col;

  z-index: 1;
}
```

or if you're using css-in-js framework like styled-components or emotion, you can write something like this:

```
const colStyles = (zIndex = 0) => css`
  position : relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: ${zIndex};

  &_box {
    display : none;
  }
`;


const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  &__rightCol {
    ${colStyles(0)};
  }

  &__leftCol {
    ${colStyles(1)};
  }
`
```

Update: Less

```
.col {
  position : relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  &_box {
    display : none;
  }
}

.rightCol {
  .col();
  z-index: 0;
}

.leftCol {
  .col();
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: its a less file, so instead of @mixin ? what should be used

Comment: I've updated my answer, you can take a look